# Geb. Access head element contents (script/stylesheet/title…)

Tags: testing, webdriver, geb

I'm trying to get contents of head section of my page. I use selector which returns correct tree node and I can traverse it and get tagNames/attributes, but all texts seems empty.

**For the html:**

`<head>
  <script>alert("MSG")</script>
</head>`

`$("head").children()*.text() // all empty
assert $('head script').text() == "" // assert true, so apparently text() is empty.
assert $("head script").@innerHTML == 'alert("MSG")' // finally works`

I can see text in `driver.pageSource`

Do I need to specify some option to parse head, or it's completely impossible?

**EDIT:**
Added html example and more code explanations. Apparently `@innerHTML works`, and as far as I understood it goes through WebDriver `.getAttribute("innerHTML");` method.

For me it's a bit surprising, why text() method doesn't work for head. So, **thanks to @jk47** I have managed to solve problem and access elements, but *generally speaking, question **"why I can't access elements of head same way I can access elements of the body"** still exists*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to post the HTML of the `<head>` element you're trying to interact with, but I believe you can do this:

For the HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>This is the title!</title>
</head>
```

You can then use:

```
$("head title").@innerHTML
```

To get the text of the title tag.

EDIT:

As to why `.text()` doesn't work, it is because Geb is calling into Selenium's `WebElement.getText()` method, which from the [API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29) states:

> Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace.

As `<head>` elements are containers for meta-data, their contents are never displayed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have extended question. Basicly - yes, your solution works. Probably innerHTML will return slightly different results, than, for example `title` method. (&nbsp; handling and so on.)